# Are postdoctoral scholars considered students or researchers in other countries?

Tags: postdocs, titles, international

I am currently working under a post-PhD (postdoc) scholarship. In my country (Argentina) I am usually considered still a *student* (although it's kind of a gray area).

In other countries, would I qualify as a *student* or as a *researcher*?

Comment: For what purpose do you want to know? Also: Why would you not describe your situation more precisely (as in this question)?

Comment: The purpose in particular is this https://education.github.com/discount_requests/new. The options are Student/Researcher and some others, but those are the ones that would apply to me. Why is the purpose important? What "question" do you mean?

Comment: The purpose is important because at the end of the day you want to accurately communicate information and thus it matters what particular aspect of your current status is relevant to the recipient of this communication. *Question* was referring to your question as you managed to describe your situation in two sentences. Regarding Github: Is *Student/Researcher* one option or are these two seperate options? Because you are certainly somewhere in between.

Comment: No, Student is an option and Researcher another.

Comment: Just wondering, isn't a student somebody paying an institution and a researcher somebody getting paid by an institution? And yes, there might be gray areas (paid internships), but that's how I always drew the line. (Just feeling hesistant to give that as an answer as none of the 700 people who saw this question noted that as a difference)

Comment: @DavidMulder as I commented below, in my country the majority of Universities are free, so as a student you pay nothing. Also you can be doing your PhD or post-Phd and receive money, although not a usual salary but as a scholarship, which smudges the area even more.

Comment: @Gabriel: Still, in the case of 'free' universities it's just you and others paying for you through taxes. Additionally scholarships are per definition financial aid for students, so that seems to be pretty clear cut.

Comment: @DavidMulder I don't get your point about taxes. Yes, everybody pays taxes, is everybody a "student"? I pay for roads too but I'm not a trucker. It's not that clear cut since researchers also are able to obtain financial aid for courses, travels abroad, etc. Also, see the accepted answer below for another good point.

Comment: @Gabriel: He? All I said was that everybody is paying for a student's tuition through taxes at a 'free' university. Not that everybody is a student. And yes it is that clear cut, if it's called scholarship it's for students, just checked 3 different definitions.

Comment: @DavidMulder your comment about taxes is 100% out of place. It has nothing to do with the question and apparently a lot to do with your conservative/libertarian inclinations. The last part of your comment is reasonable though, you might want to post it as a answer.

Comment: @Gabriel: He? Conservative/Libertarian inclinations? What? What in the world are you talking about even? The government pays for students to get educated (their tuition), the government is an organization run by the people and paid by the people, so all I said was that in the end through taxes somebody is still paying that the university can offer their courses for free to you and that your argument that universities are free in your country just doesn't change anything.

Comment: @DavidMulder again: your conservative/libertarian comments are completely out of place. The fact that in my country Universities are **free** is quite relevant regarding your original cmmt: _"isn't a student somebody paying an institution"_ since I am in fact **not** paying anybody (and neither is any other student) and hence your argument is not applicable. That taxes pay to maintain Universities on the other hand **is** indeed absolutely irrelevant since it adds nothing towards resolving the issue. It is just an out of place commentary by someone with conservative/libertarian  inclinations.

Comment: @Gabriel: "fact not paying anybody"... Yes you're are... you're paying the government and the tuition is just spread out and distributed over all ages and normalized for wealth... that's not conservative or libertarian or anything, that's just economics 101... and it does add to the issue as it clear up the issue why you aren't explicitly paying the university, but still are a student.

Comment: @DavidMulder you libertarian technicalities indeed add _absolutely nothing_. I am not _"explicitly paying the university"_ because, as I clearly explained in my first commt answering you, Universities are **free** in my country (because my country gives a d@mn :). There's no "issue" to clear up there (unless of course you have so rooted libertarian/conservative inclinations such as yourself), much less regarding your original argument that _" isn't a student somebody paying an institution_" after I specifically explained that such point was 100% immaterial to the issue at hand.

Comment: @DavidMulder: "Still, in the case of 'free' universities it's just you and others paying for you through taxes" - yes, but the same can be said about some of the researchers' salaries.

Comment: Sometimes, postdoc is considered to be an abbreviation for "post-doctoral student". This has no practical meaning, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a poll, not a question.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In general, if you are not enrolled in any course and also are not enrolled in a program in which you may eventually earn a degree, you are not a "student."

Comment: That's not necessarily true. In Quebec (Canada), postdocs have a mixed status--they're registered as students at the university and get some tax benefits as such on the provincial taxes, but not the Federal taxes.

Comment: This does not hold in many countries - and universities might officially consider you a 'student' just to sidestep labor law and employ you in worse conditions in many respects...

Comment: At my university you are considered as student if you are working towards a PhD and do not earn more than a given amount of money or you are enrolled in a bachelor's or master's program, regardless of the income. There are just too many different rules to give a general rule of thumb!

Answer (score 7):

I think postdocs are assumed to be employees as research staff (not students) of each university , as far as they have contracts with universities and may receive salaries. They do not take courses in the university. They conduct some researches in a research group in collaboration with professor(s) there. Their research topic may be something very close to their PhD project, something near to their PhD research in other concept (such as interdisciplinary projects), or something very different.

PS: Some PhD students also have research contracts with universities and are assumed to be employees of those universities, but I think their difference with a postdoc is that they receive a degree but postdocs are not receiving any degrees.

Comment: All of the things you say about postdocs could also be true of PhD students in some places/fields. So these things don't serve to distinguish between "student" and "researcher."

Comment: @ff524 Or PhD candidates in those places aren't really “students”…

Answer (score 4):

It's also relatively common in the USA for post-docs to have non-university appointments. There are many government and private labs that hire post-docs to do research as employees. These positions have various levels within their respective companies/labs.

For instance, I am a postdoc at a USA national laboratory. Here, postdocs are considered long-term temporary employees (with some reduced benefits and a reduced salary compared to a full staff member as you would expect). We aren't considered students or under any particular education program, though there are development programs offered to help in the transition between a full-time student position and a full-time research position.

Answer (score 3):

Just to further show the range of possibilities, in the US in mathematics, postdocs are usually considered **faculty**.  (In particular, they are university employees, and not students.)  They usually have (light to moderate) teaching duties, and often have official titles involving words like "[lecturer](https://wumath.wustl.edu/node/679)", "[instructor](https://math.mit.edu/about/employment.php)" or "[assistant professor](http://www.math.cornell.edu/m/Positions/faculty/hcwang)".  Of course, they are still temporary positions of 1-4 years or so, and are not tenure track.

Comment: In my Australian university, Postdocs are considered *faculty* in all fields not just math : )

Answer (score 0):

In Australia, postdocs at universities are academic research staff with fixed-term contracts. They have the same salary and working conditions as permanent academic research staff at the same level (typically level A or B), though permanent staff would usually be hired at level B or above.

Comment: By academic staff do you mean faculty? If not this only holds for some universities because postdocs are considered faculty at my Australian University.

Comment: Yes. "Faculty" is a term less often used in Australia than elsewhere. Most universities have "academic staff" (i.e. faculty) and "general staff" (i.e. everyone else -- admin staff, technicians, IT staff and so on). Postdocs are academic staff.