# Should postdoc be listed under Employment and or Education on CV?

Tags: postdocs, cv

From what I have seen, most people list postdocs under Employment/Experience on their CV. But recently I saw one that listed a postdoc under Employment *and* Education.

Is this typical/appropriate?

NOTE: According to comments on [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/29631/746) relevant question and its answers, postdocs are kind of regarded as students, in some cases.

Comment: Also: what about *employed* PhD candidates?

Comment: @Moriarty Exactly! That is one of the reasons why I asked this question. People list RA/TA positions under Experience and their PhD under Education so I wondered if that extends to postdocs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A postdoctoral associate/fellow/whatever [is usually an employee](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/who-actually-is-a-post-doctoral-fellow/2181#2181). While the purpose of the postdoc is educational, it is not "education". A postdoc is (usually) not taking classes, following a curriculum, and completing other activities toward the earning of an academic degree/certificate/whatever. Postdocs should have a contract, do not pay tuition (or have tuition paid for them), have a definite end date to their employment (although that can be renewed), etc. Since a postdoc is an employee, it should go under employment.

However, in some fields and countries, it may be custom to place the postdoc under education because the postdoc is the journeyman stage of your academic career. Ethically, it should not be listed in both places.

Answer (score 5):

NSF [Grant Proposal Guidelines (GPG) 2015](https://www.nsf.gov/publications/pub_summ.jsp?ods_key=gpg15001&org=NSF) Biographical Sketch have PostDoc listed under both Education (although they call it "Professional Preparation"), and presumably it would be listed under the "Appointments" section too. See http://www.nsf.gov/pubs/policydocs/pappguide/nsf15001/gpg_2.jsp#IIC2f

Answer (score 4):

I would more unequivocally state that the only example I can think of a postdoctoral situation where it would be appropriate to list it under the "education" section of a CV is if one is pursuing a [*Habilitation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habilitation) in the countries that use such a system. In such a case, one is acquiring an actual "qualification" that can be recognized. In traditional postdocs, such as those offered in the US (and most other countries), there is no degree track, and no course requirements or anything else that the postdocs are following.